# winrt navigation to page instance

Tags: navigation, windows-runtime, frame

How can I navigate to already created page instance in winrt instead of navigating by type (`frame.Navigate(typeof(SomePage))`)?

Currently I just set `Window.Current` to needed page, but it is not animated and of course it would be better to provide some Back, CanGoBack logic, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Obviously it is not supported built in, but you could try setting frame.Content = existingInstance or fiddling with page.NavigationCacheMode to achieve the effect you are looking for. If that doesn't work - you can implement your own navigation frame implementation, possibly based on a ContentControl. You can also steal my code from the [AlternativeFrame](http://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/79db4cb8e6f7#WinRTXamlToolkit/Controls/AlternativeFrame/AlternativeFrame.cs) control in the WinRT XAML Toolkit in which I am trying to implement all the features of a regular Frame control with the addition of page preloading and concurrent page transition animations. I think adding support for Navigate method overload that takes a page instance would not be to hard if you are OK leaving the official Frame and Page controls behind and diving into some open source.

Comment: Thanks, overload of AlternativeFrame was easy and it solved my problem. You're making life better! Thanks again.

Comment: Would you consider a pull request?

Comment: Great answer but I would add to it that there's a reason WinRT page navigation works the way to not to re-use a page. It's simply not memory efficient to do it and with the introduction of low-cost low performance tablets it's really worth to consider this factor. Also the WinRT/Win8 SDK provides well-defined solutions to avoid page reusing. It's even easier to use it and let the OS do it's scheduling job than to implement your own solution with every possible suspension/resume scenario. You should save your data when it's requested by the page (OnSave) and load it back if you need (OnLoad).